# Calculating C and Gama for LIBSVM

Tags: matlab, opencv, libsvm

I am calculating values for C and gama for libsvm. Size of my training data is Mat(28539,96); But this search is taking a long time. My laptop is On since last two days and still search is in progress. How to solve this issue, anybody has any idea. Help will be appreciated

Comment: Number of classes I am using are seven....

Comment: Assuming you do a grid search: reduce the size of the value ranges, and/or increase the step size.

Comment: a-Jays......How can you say it will take 2 days? Do you have any idea how we can calculate time or u r telling this based on ur personal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using grid.py - inside you find the parameters

```
telnet_workers = []
ssh_workers = []
nr_local_worker = 1
```

where you can configure external helpers and the number of local threads. try to increase the number of local threads until your machine is (near) 100% loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Grid search can be a very long process especially when there is a lot of data.

What you can do is:

1. record how many time it takes to train one model
2. compute how many models the grid search will train
3. estimate roughly how much time it will take to perform the grid search.

For instance, if you want to check C from 2^0 to 2^15 each time with a higher power of 2 you will perform 16 training for the C value. If you want to try gamma between 1 and 5 you will perform 5 trainings for each gamma.

In total the grid search will do 16*5 training. If it takes 10 seconds to train one model, you will then have to wait 800 seconds for the whole grid search to finish.

Note that as C gets bigger it takes more time to compute, so you might use the biggest C value to estimate the time to train one model.

One recommended approach is to use the full range to start with, and then reduce the range and the step size in order to keep a reasonable number of training per grid search.

Example:

- Search between C = 2^0 and 2^15 and gamma = 1 and 5  --> 280 iterations
- remark that the lowest error values are in the range C = 2^4 abd C = 2^5 and gamma = 3 and 4
- Search between C = 2^3 and 2^6 and gamma = 3 and 4  (with 0.1 steps) -->  40 iterations

and so on once you are satisfied with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation alexadrekow......I am doing now experimentation according to this detial.

Comment: ok don't forget to accept the answer if you are glad with it. ;)

Comment: Good answer! A follow-up question: Why is a grid-search recommended? Shouldn't a dedicated nonlinear optimization algorithm, e.g. Nelder–Mead, give the same answer with less evaluations?

Comment: @A.Donda  Several reasons: 1) the computational time required to find good parameters by grid search is not much more than that by advanced methods since there are only two parameters. 2) Grid search can be parallelized because each couple of parameter is independant, this is not necessarely the case of more advanced methods which are often iterative processes. 3) You may not feel safe using methods which use an approximation or heuristic instead of an exhaustive search